# How to evaluate a quality of neural network for object detection in Keras?

Tags: neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I've already trained the neural network in Keras for detecting two classes of images (cats and dogs) and got accuracy on test data. Is it enough for the conclusion in the master thesis or should I do other actions for evaluating the quality of network (for instance, cross-validation)?

Comment: Are you really talking about object detection? In object detection you typically use evaluation metrics like mAP or UoI and not accuracy because you are detecting positions of objects. Or are you tallking about image classification?

Answer (score 0):

Not really, I would expect more than just accuracy from my students in any classification setup. Accuracy only evaluates that particular network on that particular test set but you would have to some extent justify the *design choices* you've made in building that network. Here are some things to consider:

1. Presumably you have some hyper-parameters you've fixed, you can investigate how these affect your results. How many filters? How many layers? and most importantly why?
2. An important aspect of object classification is how your model handles noise. Depending on your dataset, one simple way would be to pre-process the test data, blur it, invert colours etc and you'll see that your performance will drop. Why does it do that? How does the [confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) look like then?
3. What is the performance of the network? Is it fast, slow compared to another system, say [VGG](https://keras.io/applications/#vgg16)?

When you evaluate your project in general not just the network, asking why things worked helps a lot, not just why things didn't work.